# Around Bevel not work for curve converted from Knife Project

Tags: modeling

Around Bevel not work for curve converted from Knife Project
Blender V 3.2.0
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: right click the curve mesh and select convert to curve. then under curve properties u can add bevel thats nice rounded

Comment: that's what i did but it didn't work

Comment: It looks as if that object, and therefore the circle derived from it, are scaled in object-mode, Ctrl-A Apply scale  and try the whole operation again.

Comment: @RobinBetts yeah, well spotted! it definitely is scaled into the `Y` and needs `Ctrl`+`A` *> Apply Scale*.

Comment: thank you @RobinBetts , it works

Comment: thank you @Harry McKenzie , it works